# Unable to get the value from select form in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to show the product's option of product_option model in template and return the selected value to model of OrderItem by form, How should I process it in forms.py?

model.py

```
class product_option(models.Model):
  option1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  option2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  ....

class Product(models.Model):
  product_option = models.ForeignKey(product_option, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
  item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  item_option = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
```

forms.py

```
class Item_create(forms.Form):
      ???????
  class Meta:
    models = OrderItem
    fields = ('item_option', )
```

views.py

```
def product_detail_with_form(request, slug):
  details = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
  form = Item_create(request.POST or None)
  if request.method == 'POST':
      if form.is_valid():
        order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
            item=details,
            user=request.user,
            ordered=False,
            item_option=form.clean_data.get('item_option')
          )
   .....
```

html

```
{% for detail in details %}
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.item_option }}
<button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what are you getting from request.POST

Comment: I want to get the selected value of item_option